# how to get edit text field to be appeared when the user selects a number in a text field

Tags: android

I want to get the subsequent edit text fields to be appeared after user enters a number in the input text field.

ex:when the user enters 3 in the edit text field,
it has to give 3 text fields down the existing text field.

So please help me out.
thanks in advance friends.

Comment: Always post some sample of your code, it helps a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am giving you the idea how to do this.

1.get the value entered by user in text field.

2.then on click of button or some other event like user has finished entering text, run a loop which adds textfields dynamically to your layout.

3.if user has enter n,then loop should run n times.

Hope this helps you.You can ask if you have any further queries :)

xml file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/ll"
>

<EditText 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/et1"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:text="Add TextFields"/>



  </LinearLayout>

  </ScrollView>
```

Java class:

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private EditText et1;
private Button btn;
private LinearLayout ll;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   ll=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll);
   et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);
   btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);

   btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


    public void onClick(View v) {

        int value=Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString());
        for(int i=0;i<value;i++)
        {
            EditText et=new EditText(MainActivity.this);
            ll.addView(et);
        }


    }
});

}

}
```

Comment: hey thanks bro, but can you please explain it through code, so that it gets bit easy.

Comment: yaa sure..I am implementing it

Comment: @user2978725:Vote up my answer...thanx:)